# why this code only render white screen in react router dom?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I used nested routing using `react-router-dom` but the nested component only renders a white screen when go to the `/taste` url.

I'm using `react-router-dom@5.3.0`

```
<App> -> <Tasts_Main> -> <Taste_taste-screen>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: What happens when you remove `exact` from the parent route

Comment: oh it did well, when remove exact but i dont know why.."exact"is so tricky to me..

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [minimal, complete, and reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) instead of images of code. Images are not accessible, searchable or copy/pasteable, and can be more difficult to read.

Comment: @detroyWall01 `exact` is saying the route must be _exactly_ `/` and, for example, `/taste` is not exactly `/` (it's a partial match)

Answer (score 0):

i usually use v6, but reading Docs of v5 you need to specify your history to navigate. I had to add my history to make this work, also using `exact` prop inside my Route and it works well

Try this in your App.js:

```
import {Route, Router} from "react-router";
import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";


function App() {
   const customHistory = createBrowserHistory();
   return (
      <Router history={customHistory}>
         <div>
          <Route exact path="/">
              <Home />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/login">
              <Login/>
          </Route>
      </div>
  </Router>

 );
}
```

Source: https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Router/history-object